# connect with RestTemplate to Atlassian products (confluence)

Tags: spring, resttemplate, confluence

I will connect to Atlassian application confluence with Spring RestTemplate and this works:

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.set("Cookie",
        "_ga=GA1.2.62774864.1458801518; __utma=1.62774864.1458801518.1464093373.1464682866.13; __utmz=1.1458816981.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _ga=GA1.3.62774864.1458801518; ki_t=1461064684094%3B1461064684094%3B1461069734488%3B1%3B2; ki_r=; seraph.confluence=5865502%3Adaa119bfd220fe01ddb5ebfb63fadf2c1f1e24ed; mywork.tab.tasks=false; JSESSIONID=AD61DF5C74564DBB35DB251EC3C8D6AD.it-confl02; crowd.token_key=0BJ0f0iIyp0TfFJnPo1PyA00");
    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity(requestHeaders);
    HttpEntity<String> response = template.exchange("https://confluence.domain.net/rest/api/content/search?cql=space=KIIOCO",
        HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
    System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

with cookie, but I will prevent using this long cookie string. 
Is there any possibility to replace this cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you send your Basic auth as a header instead of the cookie?

I removed your cookie code, and instead sent the username and password each time, and it worked:

```
    package hello;


    import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Base64;


    public class Application {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
            RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = getHeaders();
            HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);
            HttpEntity<String> response = template.exchange("https://confluence.domain.net/rest/api/content/search?cql=space=KIIOCO",
                    HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
            System.out.println(response.getBody());
        }

        public static HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
            String plainCreds = "my-username:my-password";
            byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(plainCreds.getBytes());
            String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

            return headers;
        }
    }
```